# Datepicker CSS loaded but looks like it's not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker, adminlte

I've installed AdminLTE theme in my Laravel project. Everything works and looks fine, but the datepicker seems to be broken.

I've tried all sources of JS & CSS, even with CDNS, loaded everything from bower_components that was refering to datepicker and it still not looking like it should.

Imports looks like this:-

```js
<script src="{{asset('theme')}}/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" integrity="sha256-bLNUHzSMEvxBhoysBE7EXYlIrmo7+n7F4oJra1IgOaM=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

JS code from page looks like this:

```js
<script>
 //Date picker
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true
   });
</script>
```

And the output looks like this: http://prntscr.com/o4r6gn

.CSS and .JS files are loaded, no errors on console.log.

What's wrong? :(

Comment: You are importing both version "bootstrap-datepicker" and "bootstrap-datepicker3". Maybe it is causing the issue. Please try with only one.

Comment: Tried only with bootstrap-datepicker.css and js. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you import is not correct.
Change your import to

`<script src="{{asset('theme/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js')}}"></script>`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Both methods are working on imports.

Comment: do you miss any styling css file?

Comment: try to php artisan cache:clear. But i am pretty sure that somewhere css caused this to happen

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems that there are multiple Datepicker versions,

1. First of all remove all of them,
2. Then get the one that corresponds to your version of bootstrap,
3. Place the Datepicker CSS import after all of your CSS imports(Just before the closing `<head>` tag).
4. Place the Datepicker JS import after both JQuery and Bootstrap.js
   imports(JS should be place just before the closing `<body>` tag).

Comment: Just did it. Same result... :(

Comment: @Cicharito, i just downloaded Admin-LTE, it seems it comes bundled with its own datepicker css and js, therefore you need not to install any external css or js for datepicker, try removing them and simply using datepicker, coz its working for me

Comment: `<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker"></div><label>Date:</label></div>` try using simply this without any external library

Answer (score 0):

Try [bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css%22%20integrity=%22sha256-jO7D3fIsAq+jB8Xt3NI5vBf3k4tvtHwzp8ISLQG4UWU=%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%20/%3E)
in my case it doesnt work either without these styles